# Cannot connect to internet via LAN (wireless is OK)

Tags: networking, ethernet

today I've just installed Xubuntu to my laptop. Altough I'm able to connect to internet  by wireless I cannot do it by lan. I tried all the things I've found on the web (even if I don't know what they're doing at all) but still I cannot connect.

Here is the possible valuable informations from my system. I'd be really appreatiate if some of you help me:

```
lsb_release -a
```

> No LSB modules are available. Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>
> Description:  Ubuntu 17.04 Release:   17.04 Codename: zesty

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

> ## interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) auto lo iface lo inet loopback auto lo

```
ifconfig -a
```

> eno1: flags=4099  mtu 1500
>
> ```
>     ether 34:e6:d7:80:b3:a0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>     RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>     RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>     TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
>     TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>     device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7200000-f7220000
> ```
>
> lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
>           inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
>
> ```
>     inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
>     loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
>     RX packets 1020  bytes 75402 (75.4 KB)
>     RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>     TX packets 1020  bytes 75402 (75.4 KB)
>     TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> ```
>
> wlp2s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
>           inet 172.20.32.182  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.20.47.255
>
> ```
>     inet6 fe80::6548:18e7:178e:4c06  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
>     ether 5c:e0:c5:2c:b0:7d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
>     RX packets 34326  bytes 9980591 (9.9 MB)
>     RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
>     TX packets 7156  bytes 1335706 (1.3 MB)
>     TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> ```

```
 lspci -nn |grep Ethernet
```

> 00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet
>   Connection (3) I218-LM [8086:15a2] (rev 03)

My laptop is dell latitude e5450.

Comment: Does Network Manager show you that you're connected to Ethernet?  (Note that /etc/network/interfaces isn't used in most of the Desktop versions of *buntu because Network Manager is used instead)

Comment: @ThomasWard By network manager if you mean the symbol that is next to the speaker symbol on the top left of screen. The ethernet network button is not responsive there. I cannot click on it.

Comment: When you plug into the Ethernet network do you get link lights indicating activity or connection status?

Comment: No unfortunatelly, when I plug the cable nothing changes. @ThomasWard But I'm sure both cable and infastructure is working because I tested them by using another computer

Comment: @ThomasWard do you have any idea about my situation ?

Comment: Is this a corporate environment or your own personal router and network?  If it's your own network, are you sure that the ethernet cable you are using is good and that the Ethernet ports on your router or switch are enabled and not broken?

Comment: @ThomasWard its a university environment. By using the same cable I'm able to connect to internet from another computer

Comment: Most university networks I know of are MAC filtered - you need to talk to University IT to get access to a system on their LAN.  It's most likely a case that your device isn't permitted on the LAN yet so it gets no connections.